# include php arrays to another page

Tags: php

i dont know what i need, just help me someone to fix this.

the url:

```
 url.php?id=name1 >> Not Found
 url.php?id=name4 >> Not Found
```

the php code:

```
$pages_array= array (file_get_contents('test.php'));
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    if (!in_array($_GET['id'], $pages_array)) {

        echo "OK"
    }
    else {
        echo "Not Found";
        break;
    }
}
```

test.php is like this:

```
'name1','name2','name3'
```

and when i use this it work perfectly

```
$pages_array= array ('name1','name2','name3');
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    if (!in_array($_GET['id'], $pages_array)) {
        echo "OK"
    }
    else {
        echo "Not Found";
        break;
    }
}
```

url:

```
url.php?id=name1 >> OK
url.php?id=name4 >> Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert you strings  into `array`.

Use the `,` for your splitter and use [explode method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split a string by string.

```
$pages_array= array (explode(',',file_get_contents('test.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

convert your string to array using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$pages_array = explode(',', file_get_contents('test.php'));
```